# jquery append() is ignoring <span> tags

Tags: jquery

I have crashed into an strange behavior of jquery `append()`.

Consider this two similar HTML strings, both valid markup.

```
var ids='Hello, <i>world</i>!<br/>';
var sds='Hello, <span>world</span>!<br/>';
```

when appended to a DOM element

```
$('#debug').append(ids);
$('#debug').append(sds);
```

the `<span>` tag gets removed! and the result is

> Hello, *world*!
>   Hello, !

When inspecting my DOM, I see no `<span>` in the html

[image: inspect]

what can be the reason of this removal?

---

**final EDIT**

I found the problem. It happened to be a bug in a totally unrelated piece of code. To cut the story short, here is the reason.

I had this

```
 $("span").foo().bar().appendTo($id);
```

instead of

```
 $("<span>").foo().bar().appendTo($id);
```

so, it removed all `<span>` tags from where they belonged.

Comment: Possibly css hiding `span`? Inspect HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kdjqqbhb/1/

Comment: inspecting my HTML, I don't see the <span> tag at all ! who is the culprit ??

Comment: @PA Most likely not the code you have given us. Are you using any third party tools, filters, etc? How exactly are you running the content? Are you sure there isn't code that is possibly stripping out `<span>` for whatever reason?

Comment: I have stripped down the code, I have changed the id to "debug" just in case there was some css applied, and I have posted the html. This is driving me nuts. There must be something, I can't find.

Comment: The code that @ArunPJohny has put in a jsfiddle works just fine.

Comment: yes, I've seen the fiddle. If I remove all the other scripts in the page, it works in my page, too. The problem here is how can other scripts remove this span in the page (not hiding it, but removing it). Still investigating.

Comment: @PA check your Css property and set display: inline !important; or initial for your span

Comment: I found the problem! it was not in the CSS, but in a totally unrelated piece of javascript code!. I am updating the question.

Comment: @PA: It's always the little things that get us :P

Comment: Got caught of the selector vs creator of $()

Answer (score 0):

See the difference in following fiddles:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="debug"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var ids = 'Hello, <i>world</i>!<br/>';
var sds = 'Hello, <span>world</span>!<br/>';

$('#debug').append(ids);
$('#debug').append(sds);
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
    display: none;
}
```

[span tag without CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/zjuLh068/)

[span tag with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/02mqm70f/)

So, these fiddles ensure that you must have some problem with your CSS. There is no issue with jQuery append method.

Comment: @PA. Observe difference in my fiddles.

Comment: not a problem in the CSS, it was a problem in a distant javascript code.

Comment: Ok, but I was also able to reproduce the issue using CSS.